# Glyphicon not loaded when sending emails from Asp.Net Web API

Tags: html, asp.net

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
  
<head>  
    <title></title> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head> 

<body>
<br/>

<table style="width:100%;">
 <tr>
 
  <td style="width:3%;height:60px; background-color:rgb(116,178,48);">
    </td>
    
    <td style="width:15%;align:center;font-size:28px;color:rgb(192,0,0);">
    <center>Attention!</center>
    </td>
    
    <td  style="width:82%; background-color:rgb(116,178,48);font-size:18px">
    <font color="white"><b><center>Your registration request on the Landowners' Portal has been denied!

</center></b></font>
    </td>
 
 </tr>
</table>

<br/>


<table style="width:100%;">

 <tr>
 
  <td style="width:5%;">
    </td>
    
 <br/>
 
    <td style="width:60%;">
    
    <h4>Hi, </h4> 
 
 <p>Your request to register on the Landowners' Portal has been denied.
 </p>
 
    <p>Please contact the <a href="">Land Services Team</a> for any further queries.

 </p>


 
 Best Regards, <br/>
 Land Services Team<br/>
 JKS Resources<br/>

 
    </td>
 
 <td style="width:30%;align:center">
 
<div style="border: 1px solid #67bd45;">

<h1 style="font-size:17px;color:rgb(0,151,204);text-align:center;">Have any questions?</h1>  
 <a>
      <center>    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>1- 125-552-1972 </center>    
  </a>
  <br/>  
  
   <a href="mailto:Payments@jks.com?" style="color:#337ab7;background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00);font-style:italic" class="navLink">
   <center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>Land-Lease-Payments@jks.com </center> 
  </a>
  <br/>  <br/>

</div>  
     
    
    </td>
    
  <td style="width:5%;">
    </td> 
 </tr>

  






</table>

</body>

</html>
```

I have an HTML email template and it is referring the bootstrap to load glyphicon images. The images are showing correctly when html file is opened.

But I am using this email template in ASP.NET Web API to send emails. After receiving the email, not able to see the Glyphicon images?

Please help..[Web API - Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHeth.png)

Comment: show us the code. So that we could help you.

Comment: If that font is not installed on the client pc, they will not display. Also embedding font in an email does not work.

Comment: I have checked in my local machine and seeing same issue.

Comment: Please verify code files that I attached

Comment: Email supports only basic html and css: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/. It is not the same as a website.

Comment: Thank You. Is there any approach to show the Glyphicon image.